# Checkbox Custom Validator with ValidationSummary not working

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, customvalidator

I have the following validation which is working fine for the rest of my fields, but trying to get a custom validator to work as part of the validation summary for a checkbox but no joy.

This is what I have at the moment

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function ValidateTandCs(source, args)
{
    args.IsValid = document.getElementById('<%= optIn.ClientID %>').checked;
}
</script>

<asp:ValidationSummary CssClass="highlight"
    id="ValidationSummary1" 
     HeaderText="<p>Please amend these errors below to continue with your 
         application.</p>" Runat="server" />

<asp:CheckBox id="optIn" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox> I agree to the terms and 
               conditions of this site and I wish to Opt In for registration.
<asp:CustomValidator ID="valTandCs" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateTandCs" 
     ValidationGroup="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" 
     ErrorMessage="Please accept Terms and Conditions before submitting.">
</asp:CustomValidator>
```

But when I click submit I only see the error messages for my other fields and nothing for this checkbox...any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

You had this in your code:

```
 document.getElementById('<%= optIn.ClientID %><%= optIn.ClientID %>').checked;
```

change it to:

```
 document.getElementById('<%= optIn.ClientID %>').checked;
```

Also set `ControlToValidate` property for `CustomValidator`:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="valTandCs" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateTandCs" 
 ControlToValidate="optIn" //
 ValidationGroup="ValidationSummary1" runat="server"
```

Comment: I can actually add a controltovalidate on a checkbox i get this error Control 'optIn' referenced by the ControlToValidate property of 'valTandCs' cannot be validated.

Comment: I changed this line document.getElementById('<%= optIn.ClientID %>').checked;
 but it still isnt appearing in the Validation Summary and the page still validates even when not ticked. Any Ideas ?